# CentOS returning 403 for all https URLs

Tags: centos

We've found that all https URLs on a CentOS 6 VPS are returning a 403, across multiple vhosts. Is there a config setting somewhere that I should be looking for to check what's going on? Or a log to help debug?

Answer (score 1):

Your logs are in `/var/log/httpd` (you'll need to be 'root' to view them).  You'll find `access_log` and `error_log` in there.

Have you set/checked the permissions on your files?  The group `apache` should be able to read them as a minimum.  For example, if I (user `gareth`) have a site at `/var/www/html` then:-

```
$ls -l /var/www/html
-rwxr-----. gareth apache 30 Jun 23 13:35 test.html
```

As you can see, I have `rw` access to the file and the apache service has `r` access. Also:-

```
$ls -ld /var/www/html
drwx--x---. gareth apache 4096 Jun 23 13:35 /var/www/html/
```

The directory containing the website must have the `x` permission for the `apache` group so that apache can read the directory.  Similarly, it's parent directory must also have the `x` permission set.  And the parent's parent etc.

If permissions on the file are OK, check that `SELinux` isn't the culprit.  Run:-

```
`setenforce 0`
```

and try again.  If it works now, the problem is due to `SELinux`.  Remember to run:-

```
`setenforce 1`
```

to re-enable SELinux.

Comment: Are you sure apache will return 403 (and not 500 or 404) because of a permissions issue?

Comment: Hmmmm... I tailed the logs and didn't spot any errors when hitting an example URL. The permissions appear correct but just so I know I'm checking right, how do I check the apache user rights specifically? SELinux was set to Enforcing but setting to Permissive made no difference.

Comment: @goldilocks - You got me worried there for a second!  I've just double-checked by creating a test.html file and making sure `apache` couldn't read it and the result was '403 Forbidden'.

Comment: @RussBack - you say you didn't spot any errors.  Did you spot any activity in the access log?

Answer (score 0):

A 403 status code indicates that the client cannot access the requested resource. This would typically indicate that the files and/or directory that the URL is referencing does not have permissions such that the HTTP server is allowed access it.

Confirm that the username/group used by the HTTP server has sufficient privileges to access this directory. Additionally you should see info about this in the `/var/log/httpd/access_log`, if the HTTP server is Apache, for example.

Apache's user/group are defined in the config file, `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

#### Example

```
$ grep -E "^User|^Group" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
User apache
Group apache
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a problem with an installation of mod-spdy-beta_current_x86_64.rpm. Removing that and restarting the server resolved it.